# Coriolis effect and Cyclones

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, earth, coriolis-effect, weather

The Coriolis force predicts that winds in the northern hemisphere should be deflected in a clockwise pattern and winds in the southern hemisphere should be deflected in an anti-clockwise pattern. Why is it that in the case of cyclones however, the cyclones spin anti-clockwise in the northern hemisphere and clockwise in the southern hemisphere?

If it's indeed true then what is clockwise and anti-clockwise direction?!

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the Coriolis effect in the **Northern** hemisphere the air is deflected to the **right** relative to the direction of motion of the air.
So in the Northern hemisphere if the wind is moving **North** it is deflected **East**, and if the wind is moving **South** it is deflected **West**.

The sketch below shows air moving towards a region of low pressure the eye of a typhoon/cyclone/hurricane and being deflected to forms a body of air moving in an anticlockwise direction.

[image]

Comment: How does that answer the question? By that logic and that graphic, it still seems like a hurricane in the northern hemisphere should rotate clockwise, and vice versa in the southern hemisphere; yet in reality it's the opposite. Why is that? That's what they were asking.

Comment: The diagram is for the movement of air in the Northern hemisphere with an anticlockwise rotation.